# How can i move the characters at random speed range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now all the objects are moving at the same speed using moveSpeed global variable.

```
private void MoveToNextFormation()
    {
        float step = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            squadMembers[i].transform.LookAt(newpos[i]);
            if (randomSpeed == true)
            {
                step = Random.Range(3, 50) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            squadMembers[i].transform.position =
            Vector3.MoveTowards(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpos[i], step);
            if (Vector3.Distance(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpos[i]) < threshold)
            {
                if (squareFormation == true)
                {
                    Vector3 degrees = new Vector3(0, -90f, 0);
                    Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(degrees);
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternion, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, qua[i], rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to add this part:

```
if (randomSpeed == true)
            {
                step = Random.Range(3, 50) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
```

But it's not effecting on the speed movement.
I want each character to move in another speed.

Comment: Generate random speed in the beginning then use it to move the character?

Comment: "But it's not effecting on the speed movement. I want each character to move in another speed." Have you tried stepping through with a debugger or even printed the `step` on each iteration? `step = Random.Range(3, 50) * Time.deltaTime;` is innocent enough code, maybe it's just never hit?

Comment: are you sure `randomSpeed == true`?

Comment: I see that the value in step is float numbers like 0.454 or 0.76 or 0.343
So i wonder with this values how it should move at any speed at all ? 0.4 or 0.7 seems very low speed no?
But if the randomSpeed is unchecked and the speed is used by the Range attribute it does change the speed even if the value in step is 0.456 or 0.734

So first how do i make the random speed part ?
And second why the speed values are float numbers and very low ? I guess i don't understand yet how this Time.deltaTime is working ?

Comment: @Programmer I will also init the random speed in the beginning but i want to make that when i checkuncheck the randomSpeed bool it will effect the speed in real time while the game is running that's why i put it in the MoveToNextFormation method. But i guess i messed it all somehow.

Comment: Delta means "change in", `Time.deltaTime` is the change in time since the last frame, measured in seconds, so basically 1/framerate. If you're updating with user framerate then you can multiply your transform calculations by dt so translations over time are consistent across all framerates.